# What should I do to have multiple ctypes data types assigned to a single ctypes instance in Python?

Tags: python, pointers, dll, pass-by-reference, ctypes

I'm converting a C code into a Python code that uses a .dll file.
The syntax for accessing the commands from the DLL is given below:

```
cnc_rdmacro(unsigned short FlibHndl, short number, short length, ODBM *macro);
```

**C code**
Pointer to the odbm data structure is as follows:

```
typedef struct  odbm {
    short   datano ;    /* custom macro variable number */
    short   dummy ;     /* (not used) */
    long    mcr_val ;   /* value of custom macro variable */
    short   dec_val ;   /* number of places of decimals */
} ODBM ;
```

C code used to access the dll command:

```
  short example( short number )
{
        ODBM macro ;
        char strbuf[12] ;
        short ret ;
        ret = cnc_rdmacro( h, number, 10, &macro ) ;
```

The python code that I converted according to the above C code is as follows:

```
import ctypes
fs = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(r".dll filepath")
ODBM = (ctypes.c_short * 4)() #the datatype conversion code from the above C code
ret = fs.cnc_rdmacro(libh, macro_no, 10, ctypes.byref(ODBM))
```

I can get the output without any errors in the above code.

The actual data structure of the **ODBM** has declared 4 variables of datatypes short, short, long and short which are implemented in the C code. But I had declared the **ODBM** data structure in python as `ctypes.c_short * 4` i.e, 4 variables of short data types.

But my necessity is to declare the **ODBM** structure the same as in the C code and pass it to the `ctypes.byref()`.

The ultimate solution is to include multiple data types in a single variable as a `ctypes` instance. Kindly help me out.

Comment: ctypes has a class "Structure" for this. Read the docs for details.

Comment: I have tried that as well, but I was not able to come up with a solution. Help me with an explanatory code. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `ctypes.Structure` should be used here:

```
import ctypes

class ODBM(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("datano", ctypes.c_short),
                ("dummy", ctypes.c_short),
                ("mcr_val", ctypes.c_long),
                ("dec_val", ctypes.c_short)]

fs = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(r".dll filepath")
odbm = ODBM()
ret = fs.cnc_rdmacro(libh, macro_no, 10, ctypes.byref(odbm))

print(odbm.mcr_val)
```

Comment: Thank you so much Mr.Butscher. This really helped me out. Kudos for taking your time to solve my problem.